# Not being able to start vscode in root mode in Ubuntu 20

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-20.04

I edit my code inside tomcat root folder. So I need VSCode to run in mode. I used to write `sudo code --user-data-dir` and VSCode happily started in root mode. However I do not know what exactly happened yesterday and vscode doesn't simply respond. It doesn't start at all and neither is their any error message. Please help. Noob here

Comment: update : apparently there has been update somewhere. And now you need to run the following "sudo code --user-data-dir --no-sandbox"

Answer (score 1):

Update : I just figured it out. Apparently there has been an update somewhere and now you need to run `sudo code --user-data-dir --no-sandbox`

Answer (score 0):

i recommend to use alias to run code --user-data-dir="portable-vscode"

for example

```
echo "alias vscode='code --user-data-dir="portable-vscode" --no-sandbox --extension-dir portable-vscode/" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score -3):

Hey bro open the terminal and type  sudo code

Comment: Thanks. But to run code as sdo you will need a "--user-data-dir" argument. And now you will also need to add "--no-sandbox"